# Xcode 9.1 Performance Issues - How to resolve slow editor response?

Tags: performance, xcode9.1

Still having trouble with slow response in Xcode 9.1 editor.  For example: select 4 lines to paste...6 second delay with color wheel spinning.  Move cursor to edit a character, 4 second delay.  Switch from Project to Issue navigator.. 14 second delay.  Simply scrolling in a class...5 second delay!  Have bought a new iMac, have added memory, have checked all the preference settings.  Have closed all other apps, restarted, cleaned, eliminated warnings.  Evidently, there is something  something going on with my preferences/setup that is causing this slowness.  Any help would be Greatly Appreciated